# Error pushing changes to cloud foundry

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, devops, ibm-cloud-tools

from my local host, I connected to blue mix with

```
 cf api https://api.ng.bluemix.net
```

I logged in and then I pushed the changes with

```
 cf push
```

However, in the console,

```
 Uploading MY_PROJECT...
 Uploading app files from: /Users/MyName/Documents/MY_PROJECT
 Uploading 437.7K, 386 files
 Done uploading               
 FAILED
 Error processing app files: Error uploading application.
 The resource file mode is invalid: File mode '0444' is invalid.
 (venv) My-iMac:MY_PROJECT MyName$
```

How do I trouble shoot this?

Comment: What cf CLI version is that on? We have a fix for an error like this in cf CLI 6.14.1 (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases/tag/v6.14.1).

Comment: 6.22.1+6b7af9c-2016-09-24

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this link: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/685 the file mode must be at least 600 so I guess you should "raise" the permissions for your resources folder, even if 444 would be technically ok.

Concerning troubleshooting: the error message is right there in your output. If you need more log output, you can use the command

```
cf logs APP-NAME
```

See https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/streaming-logs.html for further details.

Comment: How exactly do I do that? The thread doesnt explain that. It only tells me what you said

Comment: cd /Users/MyName/Documents/MY_PROJECT; chmod -R 644 ./*

Comment: now I'm getingError processing app files: 

"Error uploading application.
An unknown error occurred. "

The cf log has been running for 10 minutes and no logs yet

Comment: hm - the only thing I can imagine (concerning the file permissions) is that you need 755 instead of 644. So run `chmod -R 755 ./*` inside your project directory. If the error still occurs, it seems to have nothing got to do with the file permissions.

Comment: Thank you so much. This solved the issue but I have another one now for the app staging failure lol. Im going to browse the web for the solution