# Cloud Foundry | The resource file mode is invalid: File mode '444'

Tags: jenkins, cloud-foundry

I am getting the same error that a lot of people seemingly get for example: [How to fix "The Resource file mode is invalid" on Cloud Foundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673054/how-to-fix-the-resource-file-mode-is-invalid-on-cloud-foundry)

The error is below.

```
The resource file mode is invalid: File mode '444' with path '.git/objects/pack/pack-6baf78b914aeacf64179d19a0f4aeb9edd1143e3.pack' is invalid. Minimum file mode is '0600'
```

I have not found a fix or a workaround for pushing to CF from Jenkins for this issue. The file mode on my machine is already at 777 as you can see here:

```
#:/**PATH/.git/objects/pack$ stat --format '%a' pack-6baf78b914aeacf64179d19a0f4aeb9edd1143e3.pack 777
```

I have also added a .cfignore, but that doesn't do anything. I also cannot download the CF CLI because I only have a windows machine.

Is there any way else around this?

Comment: How are you pushing with Jenkins? Are you shelling out to the cf cli? If it's not the cf cli, but a plugin or something using the API directly it might be ignoring `.cfignore`. I ask because it's weird that it's trying to push something under `.git`. The `.git` folder should be ignore even without a `.cfignore` file.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: nope, adding .cfignore didn't help me. Any alternative approaches via the jenkinsfile?